# Parsing xml with colon using libxml

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I am facing a problem when trying to parse an XML file that has "colons".

ex:

```
<PropertyList:Property>
    <property:Condition Mode="ON" />
    <property:Setting max="128" />
</PropertyList:Property>
```

While the parsing of files without colons works perfect for me.
I am using ibxml library, from xmlsoft. And the first instruction where I realise parsing is not working is when i do

```
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseFile("XMLFile.xml");
```

That returns NULL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colon within element names is not just a regular character -- it defines a [XML namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/). A namespace must be declared in order to be used - like:

```
<root xmlns:PropertyList='http://www.example.org/schema'>
```

A probable issue with your document is that it doesn't declare the used namespaces, which results in a parsing error.